# Javascript slideshow fading issue - not seamless

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

Images show below when fading, changing the content box, not seamless - it should fade out before the new image shows... not sure what's up.

http://jsfiddle.net/ucswr/

```
$("#aboutslideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
$('#aboutslideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(1000)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#aboutslideshow');
},  4200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the complete callback of fadeOut so that the next item fades in only after the other one has faded out. The reason for the behavior you are seeing is due to the async nature of fade functions. With your code snippet, it kicks off both `fadeout` and `fadeIn` without the previous animation being completed.

```
var $slideContainer = $("#aboutslideshow");
$slideContainer.children("div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $slideContainer.children('div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(this).next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo($slideContainer);
    })

}, 4200);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zDz9E/)**

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. Weird that'd it'd execute like that - stuff only pros would know!

Comment: @rootsup You are welcome. Issue is that fadout is pushed on to the animation queue and gets started and immediately fadein is pushed to the queue as well and it gets started as well. Instead you can wait for fadeout animation to complete.